# Яндекс Касса в Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, яндекс-касса

Всем привет, разрабатываю кросс-платформенное приложение на Xamarin Forms. И встал вопрос подключения Яндекс кассы. Сталкивался ли кто с данной задачей и как ее решил (внедрение кассы в xamarin)?

Comment: Яндекс вроде неплохо документирует свои API. Вы ищите готовое решение, или что именно? [Вот](https://github.com/morpher-ru/Yandex.Checkout.V3) результат 2 минут поиска.

Comment: Я находил ответы, в которых предлагалость сделать привязку Java библиотеки. Данная библиотека мне не попадалась, спасибо)